# Psychological Fitness-linked topics

Tags: discussion

This may be a first, question, answer and meta topic all from the same person.

I wanted to ask about the relevance of: [Should I tell people about my fitness goals for better accountability?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/29862/should-i-tell-people-about-my-fitness-goals-for-better-accountability)

This was a question I was asked over the weekend and I had my answer ready but I thought it would be nice to "share with the group". It is not directly linked to fitness and is more about the psychological effects of stating your fitness goals and the impact on achieving those goals.

Is this question on-topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that the question is on topic for the site, and it sort of explores an area we haven't really explored a lot, which is how to set realistic, achievable goals (except in specific cases related to a single person). I think that by addressing it from the point of view of a fitness professional asking so they can better relate to their clients is a good thing.

As far as asking a question you already know the answer to, in order to enrich the site is absolutely permitted and as can be seen [by this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking) is even encouraged, and has been for quite some time.

I would, however, encourage anyone doing this to make sure that they are questions with concrete answers that are relevant to the site, and not just interesting items that are tangential to the site purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't downvote the question or answer, but I think maybe one flaw of the question was that it applies to setting any goals regardless of the subject. The question/answer would be better if they examined how the substitution phenomenon relates specifically to physical fitness (dietary, training and physical goals) and how accountability is better established (for example, a gym buddy you meet with at set times).

Comment: Excellent point. I missed that in the original reading.

Answer (score -1):

I think these types of situations are more appropriately handled with a group FAQ.  Posting a question and answering it does not seem like a good use of this site.  I know you don't mean it that way, but, it almost seems like self promotion.

Comment: With that in mind, are there any examples of a FAQ on other SE forums?

Comment: @JJosaur Not that I'm aware of.  But, it seems like a resource that would be handy in resolving many of the duplicate questions that are asked here.